# Is there a way in Django to make it so that when a form with initial text is clicked the text disappears?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, forms

For example, on some sites in the username form box it says something like "username" and then when you click there the "username" disappears so you can type your username.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a django issue.

Comment: Look up `placeholder`

Comment: @Marcin it depends whether he wants it declared it in his Form-model or not

Comment: Yes I do want it in the Form-model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in a form.

```
Username =forms.CharField(max_length=35,
                          required=True, 
                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
```

Check out the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances) for more on how to customize HTML from Django Forms.

Comment: Is there an easy way to set the placeholder text to be the field's label?

Comment: set variable with placegolder text, then do 'placeholder': my_label and label=my_label

Comment: That won't set the placeholder to be the label, that will just set the label.

Comment: Username =forms.CharField(label=my_label,max_length=35, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': my_label}))`

Comment: So I have to use a variable? There is no way to directly reference the label?

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot hard code it in. Are you dynamically creating it or something? A variable seems like your best shot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use html for that:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="This text will disappear" />
```